# Make joyplot/ridgeline plot using dates as the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, ridgeline-plot

I am plotting a **joyplot where the x-axis is a range of dates**. However, joyplot only accepts dates arguments as numbers... As a result, the chart is plotted correctly, but the x-axis displays dates as their serial number, which is not very friendly to the end user.

I have tried various methods to format the axis (like this one: [Set x axis labels for joyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366767/set-x-axis-labels-for-joyplot)), but none worked so far!

**How can I format the x-axis so that it displays dates in the 'mm.yyyy' format (eg.: 01.2022)?**

I am using the following database to plot this example (saved as a .csv to my computer):
https://www.boxofficemojo.com/genre/sg4242469121/?ref_=bo_gs_table_24

Table example (copy it and paste in a .csv file, naming it "Example", as in code below):

| Title | Release Date | Date | Distributor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Incredibles 2 | Jun 15, 2018 | 43252 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| The Lion King | Jul 19, 2019 | 43647 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Finding Dory | Jun 17, 2016 | 42522 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Frozen II | Nov 22, 2019 | 43770 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Shrek 2 | May 19, 2004 | 38108 | DreamWorks |
| Toy Story 4 | Jun 21, 2019 | 43617 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Toy Story 3 | Jun 18, 2010 | 40330 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Frozen | Nov 22, 2013 | 41579 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| The Secret Life of Pets | Jul 8, 2016 | 42552 | Universal Pictures |
| Despicable Me 2 | Jul 3, 2013 | 41456 | Universal Pictures |
| Inside Out | Jun 19, 2015 | 42156 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Zootopia | Mar 4, 2016 | 42430 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Finding Nemo | May 30, 2003 | 37742 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Minions | Jul 10, 2015 | 42186 | Universal Pictures |
| Shrek the Third | May 18, 2007 | 39203 | DreamWorks |
| The Lion King | Jun 15, 1994 | 34486 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Up | May 29, 2009 | 39934 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |
| Minions: The Rise of Gru | Jul 1, 2022 | 44743 | Universal Pictures |
| The Grinch | Nov 9, 2018 | 43405 | Universal Pictures |
| Sing | Dec 21, 2016 | 42705 | Universal Pictures |
| Monsters University | Jun 21, 2013 | 41426 | Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures |

Code:

```
import joypy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\Example.csv', delimiter=';') #replace file name and directory with your file, created from the table above
print(df.shape)
df.head()

fig, ax = joypy.joyplot(df, 
                        by = 'Distributor', 
                        column='Date', 
                        colormap=cm.autumn, 
                        figsize = (10,6),
                        fade = True)
```

Output plot:

[image]

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my system

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question and inserted table containing a sample of the data (just some lines of the table contained in the link of the question, I think it suffices for a simple test). You must copy it and save as a .csv in your computer.

Comment: I think you want to employ the `parse_dates` kwarg in `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: I tried it before... It gives the following error: "No numeric values found. Joyplot requires at least a numeric column/group". The plot only works when I transform the dates to numbers in the source (i.e., make 'Jun 15, 2018' = 43252). But then I don't want the xticks to retain this 'weird' look, I need it to display a date, like '06.2018'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please accept that the x-axis tick values in my answer may not be correct; it is unclear what the value obtained by `ax[-1].get_xticks()` indicates. Assuming it represents days, I can change it to a date in the following way: since the time series in maplotlib is Gregorian standard, I convert it from a number to a date.

```
df['Release Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Release Date'], format='%b %d, %Y')

import joypy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = joypy.joyplot(df, 
                        by = 'Distributor', 
                        column='Date', 
                        colormap=cm.autumn, 
                        figsize = (10,6),
                        xrot=45,
                        fade = True)

print(ax[-1].get_xticks())
new_dates = [mdates.num2date(x +  mdates.date2num(np.datetime64('1900-01-01'))) for x in ax[-1].get_xticks()]
new_dates = [t.strftime('%b-%Y') for t in new_dates]
ax[-1].set_xticklabels(new_dates)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My response also creates dates from hypotheticals.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the dates in the x-axis with help from the link you provided. I wanted to go through it in a bit of detail here.

**Code for reading and formatting data**

As joyplot only takes numbers, I converted the strings (Jan2, 2018 format) to dates and put them in Date column. Then to numbers using ordinal. I mention this because the numbers above are slightly different. It should not matter...

```
import joypy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx') ## Copy pasted data into excel
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Release Date'], format = '%b %d, %Y')
df['Date_Number'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:x.toordinal())
```

**Create array to be used for axis**

This is similar to what was in the other SO post. But, the data was from some time in 1991 to 2023. So, hardcoded them. Used 9 ticks as I thought that the 32 years would blend well having 8 interim labels. Also, used `-12` so that just the year and month would show up. I think as all are Jan, you can remove that as well. Will leave it up to you...

```
# Generate date strings from a manually set start date
numdays = 9
start_date = "01-Jan-1991"
dates = pd.date_range(start = "01-Jan-1991", end ='01-Jan-2023',periods=numdays)
dates = [str(date)[:-12] for date in dates]
```

**Plot graph and adjust the axis**

As in the other post, used ax[-1] to get the last axis. But do note that I have used the `set_ticks()` to get the ticks, then the `set_ticklables()` for the labels and finally the `xlim()` to set the ends of the start and end points, like so...

```
fig, ax = joypy.joyplot(df,  by = 'Distributor', column='Date_Number', 
                        colormap=matplotlib.cm.autumn, figsize = (10,6), fade = True)

ax[-1].set_xticks(range(numdays))
ax[-1].set_xticklabels(dates)
ax[-1].set_xlim([0, 8])
```

**...and the resulting plot is**

[image]